# Nagios - obsessing over this service: what does this mean?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

We use Nagios to monitor our servers. I haven't set this up myself, and I want to change some settings. Most services have the setting *obsessing* enabled. I wonder what this means, and what happens if I disable it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Nagios docs](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#service) explain this setting as:

> This directive determines whether or not checks for the service will be "obsessed" over using the ocsp_command.

The ocsp_command is explained [here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html#ocsp_command). This is the "Obsessive Compulsive Service Processor Command."

> This option allows you to specify a command to be run after every service check, which can be useful in distributed monitoring.
>
> This command is only executed if the obsess_over_services option is enabled globally and if the obsess_over_service directive in the service definition is enabled.

[Red Hat says](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/3/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch08s02.html) the option should be disabled unless you are doing distributed monitoring.

So if obsess_over_services is enabled globally, you should check your ocsp_command. Disabling the obsess_over_service option for a service means that the ocsp_command will not run each time that service is checked.

Comment: Why is distributed monitoring considered "obsessive"? I don't follow the thought process here and so I'm sure I'll be looking for this info again in <6months.